# WPF Binding (Using Trigger) not working from TextBox to Label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Friends, I am new to WPF MVVM structure.
I was trying to copy TextField value to a Label using Trigger. What I was doing is in below xaml code.

**VehicalForm.xaml**

```
        <Window x:Class="Seris.VehicalForm"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">
<Control>
    <Control.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 " >
                <Label Content="Vehical No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicalNo}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="Model_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Manufacturing Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <DatePicker Name="ManufacturingDate_DateTime" SelectedDate="{Binding ManufacturingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="IU No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" Width="80" Name="IUNO_Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IUNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Content="Personnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ComboBox Name="Personnel_Combo" SelectedValue="{Binding PersonnelNameSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonnelName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="116"/>
                <Separator Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="16"/>
                <Button Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding SaveButton_Command}" Content="Save" Width="66"/>
                <Label x:Name="Error_Label" Content="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Width="137"/>
                <ListView Name ="Grid" Height="294" Width="371" >
                    <DataGrid Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="Cell" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderThickness="0">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehical No" Binding="{Binding VehicalNo}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" Binding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="IUNo" Binding="{Binding IUNo}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Personnel" Binding="{Binding PersonnelNameSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>
                </ListView>
                <Label Name="Notification" Content="hjgj"/>

            </WrapPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=VehicalNo_Text}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="Notification" Value="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Template>
</Control>
</Window>
```

Here I am unable to Bind value of "Vehical_Text" to Label named as "Notification.
So my question is,

1) How to do this successfully using trigger
2) I couldn't find IsMouseClick. If I need mouseClick event which property to set.

Comment: Just so I am clear on what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting to click a specific VehicleNo in your datagrid and then have the notification label change to the Vehicle number you clicked on?

Comment: you are setting the `Value` to `Text`, but what `Text` are you meaning, you will need to define what element you want Text to come from to apply to `Notification`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can declare your textbox-event-handlers in XAML Using  **Preview-events** (i.e. PreviewMouseDown,PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown etc)

**Sample1**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <TextBox.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Notification" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding ElementName=VehicalNo_Text,Path=Text}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>               
        </TextBox.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="Notification"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Sample2**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <TextBox.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseDoubleClick">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Notification" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding ElementName=VehicalNo_Text,Path=Text}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBox.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="Notification" Content="change content"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the binding part, you can try

```
<Label Name="Notification"  
       Content="{Binding ElementName=VehicalNo_Text,  
       Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

As for the trigger part are you referring to the label? If so, you can try these:

```
MouseDoubleClick="someEvent"
MouseDown="anotherEvent"/>
```

**Update:** 
With example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586(v=vs.110).aspx).
Need to set Name for Control:

```
<Control Name="someControl">
```

Then accessing element inside the control upon trigger,

```
private void whatEverControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var text2paste = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    var target = (Label)someControl.Template.FindName("Notification", someControl);
    target.Content = text2paste;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need in terms of Trigger only.

Comment: which component do you intend to raise the trigger?

Comment: The same Label "Notification" based on TextField "Vehical_No".